# Almacenar resultado de una función en una variable

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que me retorna la dirección ip , necesito almacenar este resultado en una variable esto es lo que tengo:

```
var ipCallback;
 getIPs(function(ip){
   ipCallback = ip;
}); //pero esto me retorna un error

Pero si puedo mostrar la ip en un console.log:
getIPs(function(ip){console.log(ip);});


alert(ipCallback);//undefined


//obtiene la direccion IP:
        function getIPs(callback){
            var ip_dups = {};

            //compatibilidad exclusiva de firefox y chrome, el usuario @guzgarcia compartio este enlace muy util: http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/
            var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
                || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
                || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

            //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
            if(!RTCPeerConnection){
                //NOTE: necesitas tener un iframe in la pagina, exactamente arriba de la etiqueta script
                //
                //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
                //<script>... se llama a la funcion getIPs aqui...
                //
                var win = iframe.contentWindow;
                RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
                    || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
                    || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            }

            //requisitos minimos para conexion de datos
            var mediaConstraints = {
                optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
            };

            var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

            //construccion de una nueva RTCPeerConnection
            var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

            function handleCandidate(candidate){
                // coincidimos con la direccion IP
                var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
                var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

                //eliminamos duplicados
                if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                    callback(ip_addr);

                ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
            }

            //escuchamos eventos candidatos
            pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

                //dejamos de lado a los eventos que no son candidatos
                if(ice.candidate)
                    handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
            };

            //creamos el canal de datos
            pc.createDataChannel("");

            //creamos un offer sdp
            pc.createOffer(function(result){

                //disparamos la peticion (request) al stun server (para entender mejor debemos ver la documentacion de WebRTC.
                pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});

            }, function(){});

            //esperamos un rato para dejar que todo se complete:
            setTimeout(function(){
                //leemos la informacion del candidato desde la descripcion local
                var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');

                lines.forEach(function(line){
                    if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                        handleCandidate(line);
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es porque tu función es asíncrona, y cuando le asignas un valor a tu variable de esta forma:

```
var ip = getIPs(function(ip){});
```

Tu función aún no termina de ejecutarse, por lo que esta variable tendrá un valor `nulo o undefined`

Para que funcione tendrás que hacer algo como esto

```
var ipCallback;
getIPs(function(ip){
    ipCallback = ip;
});
```

Tu variable tendría que ser global y que no esté sólo dentro del alcance de tu función `getIPs`

```js
var ipCallback;
getIPs(function(ip){
  ipCallback = ip;
  alert(ipCallback);
});
//undefined


//obtiene la direccion IP:
        function getIPs(callback){
            var ip_dups = {};

            //compatibilidad exclusiva de firefox y chrome, el usuario @guzgarcia compartio este enlace muy util: http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/
            var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
                || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
                || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

            //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
            if(!RTCPeerConnection){
                //NOTE: necesitas tener un iframe in la pagina, exactamente arriba de la etiqueta script
                //
                //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
                //<script>... se llama a la funcion getIPs aqui...
                //
                var win = iframe.contentWindow;
                RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
                    || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
                    || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            }

            //requisitos minimos para conexion de datos
            var mediaConstraints = {
                optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
            };

            var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

            //construccion de una nueva RTCPeerConnection
            var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

            function handleCandidate(candidate){
                // coincidimos con la direccion IP
                var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
                var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

                //eliminamos duplicados
                if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                    callback(ip_addr);

                ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
            }

            //escuchamos eventos candidatos
            pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

                //dejamos de lado a los eventos que no son candidatos
                if(ice.candidate)
                    handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
            };

            //creamos el canal de datos
            pc.createDataChannel("");

            //creamos un offer sdp
            pc.createOffer(function(result){

                //disparamos la peticion (request) al stun server (para entender mejor debemos ver la documentacion de WebRTC.
                pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});

            }, function(){});

            //esperamos un rato para dejar que todo se complete:
            setTimeout(function(){
                //leemos la informacion del candidato desde la descripcion local
                var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');

                lines.forEach(function(line){
                    if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                        handleCandidate(line);
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Comment: No consigo ultilzar lo que me dices, me sigue dando error , lo intento mostrar en un alert , colocando el codigo al final de la funcion getIPs y intentando mostar en un alert ipCallback

Comment: ¿Qué error te manda?

Comment: al mandar un alert de ipCallback me me retorna undefined

Comment: Si el alert lo haces afuera de tu función callback de `getIPs` seguirá siendo `undefined` aquí el truco con la asincronía es saber en que momento deberás seguir con la ejecución de tu código. Si este depende del valor de lo que te regrese `getIPs`dicho código deberá seguir adentro de la función callback.

Comment: Te recomiendo leas más afondo sobre asincronía y lo que jQuery ofrece para su manejo, como promesas, deferidos y sus métodos `done()`,  `when()` Ejemplo de promises: https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Entonces tengo que colocar var ipCallback;
getIPs(function(ip){
    ipCallback = ip;
});  dentro de la funcion asincronía getIPs lo intentare gracias

Comment: gracias por la ayuda estimado funciono !